# SQL isolate greatest values in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following output from a view:

```
xfer_id  client_plt_id xfer_doc_no
2255     80016616        KANORANJE1
2270     80016616        ORANJECFC1
2285     80016616        CFCFPT1
2285     80016623        CFCFPT1
2270     80016623        ORANCFC1
2255     80016623        KANORANJE1
2255     80016630        KANORANJE1
2270     80016630        ORANCFC1
2285     80016630        CFCFPT1
```

Where there is more than one client_plt_id with the same number I want to isolate the row with the highest xfer_id.

For client_plt_id = 80016616 that would be xfer_id = 2285 for example.

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Edit: I'm using MS-SQL 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These queries both isolate the row with the highest `xfer_id` for each distinct `client_plt_id`

```
select xfer_id, client_plt_id, xfer_doc_no
from   tab t1
where  xfer_id = (
       select max(xfer_id)
       from   tab t2
       where  t2.client_plt_id = t1.client_plt_id
   )
```

or, for mysql this may be better performing:

```
select xfer_id, client_plt_id, xfer_doc_no
from   tab t1
inner join (
       select max(xfer_id), client_plt_id
       from   tab
       group by client_plt_id
       ) t2
on     t1.client_plt_id = t2.client_plt_id
and    t1.xfer_id = t2.xfer_id
```

For both these queries, you can simply add a `WHERE` clause to select on particualr client. Just append for example `WHERE  client_plt_id = 80016616`.

If you simply want the one row with the highest `xfer_id`, regardless of `client_plt_id`, this is what you need:

```
select xfer_id, client_plt_id, xfer_doc_no
from   tab t1
where  xfer_id = (select max(xfer_id) from tab)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MAX(xfer_id), client_plt_id FROM table GROUP BY client_plt_id;
```

Comment: this does not isolate the row, it just gets yu the maximum xfer_id...and without selecting client_plt_id, you cant even see who's xfer_id you're looking at.

Comment: I intended for him to understand what is going on rather than type it in exactly, as always.

Comment: Is that a veiled reference to the fact that I didn't explain in prose? :P  Feel free to not vote up if you don't find it useful.

Comment: Roger: no, really - no hidden message. I'm not that long on SO, and I learn more and more that different people have different ways of answering. I tend to be verbose, perhaps pedantic at times, others are more terse.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE(
        xfer_id  INT,
        client_plt_id INT, 
        xfer_doc_no VARCHAR(100)

)

INSERT INTO @TABLE (xfer_id ,client_plt_id,xfer_doc_no) SELECT 2255,80016616,'KANORANJE1'
INSERT INTO @TABLE (xfer_id ,client_plt_id,xfer_doc_no) SELECT 2270,80016616,'ORANJECFC1' 
INSERT INTO @TABLE (xfer_id ,client_plt_id,xfer_doc_no) SELECT 2285,80016616,'CFCFPT1' 
INSERT INTO @TABLE (xfer_id ,client_plt_id,xfer_doc_no) SELECT 2285,80016623,'CFCFPT1' 
INSERT INTO @TABLE (xfer_id ,client_plt_id,xfer_doc_no) SELECT 2270,80016623,'ORANCFC1' 
INSERT INTO @TABLE (xfer_id ,client_plt_id,xfer_doc_no) SELECT 2255,80016623,'KANORANJE1' 
INSERT INTO @TABLE (xfer_id ,client_plt_id,xfer_doc_no) SELECT 2255,80016630,'KANORANJE1' 
INSERT INTO @TABLE (xfer_id ,client_plt_id,xfer_doc_no) SELECT 2270,80016630,'ORANCFC1' 
INSERT INTO @TABLE (xfer_id ,client_plt_id,xfer_doc_no) SELECT 2285,80016630,'CFCFPT1' 

SELECT  t.*
FROM    @TABLE t INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  client_plt_id,
                    MAX(xfer_id) Max_xfer_id
            FROM    @TABLE
            GROUP BY client_plt_id
        ) maxVals ON t.client_plt_id = maxVals.client_plt_id 
                AND t.xfer_id = maxVals.Max_xfer_id
```

Comment: Thanx, I always feel that a fully working solution **(specially Sql)** is a good example X-)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [Group By clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php).

I'd give an example, but you did not specify what database you are using.